# Cakephp3 multiple databases

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I wanted to ask, if is possible to work with 2 databases in cakephp3, using raw sql ?

I have query like this:

```
select * from shop.brochures b, upload.documents up where b.doc_id = up.id;
```

The problem is, this are 2 databases.

I don't know, how setup connection, i think that will not work ( doc example )

```
$conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
```

Thank You for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

in /config/app.php you can set as many db as you want; i have 2.

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'sisarticulos',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
    ],
'gente' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'sggeneral',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,´
```

then in the controller you can set

```
$conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
//some code
 $conn = ConnectionManager::get('get');
```

use default first and then use gente